# How many direwolves are still alive in GoT?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As of S6E05, how many of the original *Stark* direwolves are still alive?

Short of rewatching the past seasons to confirm, I believe only Jon Snow's wolf still lives. Is this correct?

Comment: Probably a lot. The ones the Stark children got weren't the only ones. ;-)

Comment: @Ragnor the belief during the first episode is that Dire Wolves are considered Extinct. Just like Dragons and Magic.

Comment: @cde - No, not that they are extinct, just exceedingly rare that far south of the Wall, if I recall correctly.  edit - From the original script: "Theon: There hasn't been a direwolf south of the Wall for two hundred years"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The status at Season 6 episode 5 is either 1 or 2, Ghost (Jon) is alive and it is unclear if Nymeria (Arya) is alive, all other wolves have been deceased.

The current (season 7 episode 2) status of the Direwolves is as follows, obviously contains spoilers:

- Ghost (Jon): Alive
- Nymeria (Arya): Alive and leading a pack of wolves (likely in the Riverlands).
- Shaggydog (Rickon): Killed by the Umbers to prove their allegiance to the Boltons.
- Summer (Bran): Killed while defending him from White Walkers and their army.
- Grey Wind (Robb): Killed at the Red Wedding
- Lady (Sansa): Killed by Ned Stark on the crown's order as retribution for Nymeria biting Joffrey (Nymeria was released by Arya before to avoid a similar fate).

Comment: [ < Spoilers > ]

Comment: @TedSly obviously, the question is basically asking for spoilers, but I've hidden the theories/book-only comments.

Comment: I agree that @BigTallJosh asked specifically about the current episode (as of today); however, the spoiler tag is for those that happen across these threads in random internets searches.    
But I do applaud your very thorough and well defined answer.

Comment: @TedSly Movies.SE spoiler policy is only to hide them in titles and first paragraph, with very minimal use of spoiler tags. This entire site is a spoiler zone, like any wikipedia or other source would be.

Comment: I think cde's last point should be plastered on the top banner. I livestream every Sunday, and thus miss GoT and usually watch it Monday after work. Thus, I avoid this SE site until I've had a chance to catch up on the show. But this site exists entirely to give additional information, and it's impossible to do that without at least some, usually a lot, of spoilers.

Comment: @KillianDS  You're most recent update isn't answering the specific text of the question:  "As of S6E05".  At the very least, I think you want to wrap anything post S6E05 in spoiler tags.  The same would apply to your edit after S6E09.  Either that or the question needs to be edited to be "As of today"

Comment: @kuhl the title does not specify an episode, only the body, but I get your point and added a s06e05 specific thing in the beginning.

Answer (score 19):

As far as I know 2 direwolves are alive.

- Rob's wolf died during the Red Wedding
- Jon's wolf still alive
- Sansa's wolf was executed instead of Arya's wolf, which attacked Joffrey.
- Arya's wolf missing but probably alive
- Bran's wolf was killed during the attack of the White Walkers.
- Rickon's wolf was beheaded by the Umbers.

Comment: @Chanandler Bong: Thanks for pointing out that it were Umbers.

Comment: Completely forgot Arya let hers run free! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @BigTallJosh It becomes rather important in the books - don't know if that'll mak into the TV-sries though...

Answer (score 6):

Nymeria has not been confirmed as killed yet as she ran away in the first season. Assuming that she is alive, it is her and Ghost.